# Laptop doesn´t go to sleep if HDD is in standby

Tags: arch-linux, power-management

So I have one mSata-SSD where my whole System is installed and one HDD where I put
my Videos and Music!

I don´t need my HDD all the Time so I put it to sleep on Startup

```
sudo hdparm -Y /dev/sda
```

The Problem I´m facing is when my HDD has the Status 'Standby' and I close my 
Laptop LID it doesn´t go to sleep anymore.

Anyone an Idea what could cause that Problem?
I´m on ArchLinux with Gnome3